# Where to define custom mixins for class based views

Tags: django, mixins, django-class-based-views

I try to define a JSON response for some kind of auto-completion in an input field (probably realized with [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)) with django class based views.

It's very hard for me to find out, what exactly I need to do to get this done. A far as I am at the moment, I realize that some kind of JSON response mixin might be useful - just as demonstrated [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html).

Where is the best place to define a custom mixin (like the JSONResponseMixin in the documentation)?

Comment: AFAIK there is no canonical way for this, if you want to reuse make it a separate django app - but I guess it is a matter of opinion and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: I have a big project and we use a util package. Most base views are in util.django.views, as an example. This is just my experience and probably it's an off-topic question

Comment: question is not clear. could you elaborate it and share some code ?